# scraping multiple pages in python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have managed to write code to scrape data from the first page and now the I am stuck with writing a loop in this code to scrape the next 'n' pages. Below is the code

I would appreciate if someone could guide/help me to write the code that would scrape the data from remaining pages.

Thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


url = requests.get('https://wsc.nmbe.ch/search?sFamily=Salticidae&fMt=begin&sGenus=&gMt=begin&sSpecies=&sMt=begin&multiPurpose=slsid&sMulti=&mMt=contain&searchSpec=s').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

elements = soup.find_all('div', style="border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 10px 0;")
#print(elements)

csv_file = open('wsc_scrape.csv', 'w')

csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

csv_writer.writerow(['sp_name', 'species_author', 'status', 'family'])


for element in elements:
    sp_name = element.i.text.strip()
    print(sp_name)



    status = element.find('span', class_ = ['success label', 'error label']).text.strip()
    print(status)




    author_family = element.i.next_sibling.strip().split('|')
    species_author = author_family[0].strip()
    family = author_family[1].strip()
    print(species_author)
    print(family)


    print()

    csv_writer.writerow([sp_name, species_author, status, family])

csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass `page=` parameter in URL and iterate over all pages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

csv_file = open('wsc_scrape.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['sp_name', 'species_author', 'status', 'family'])

for i in range(151):
    url = requests.get('https://wsc.nmbe.ch/search?page={}&sFamily=Salticidae&fMt=begin&sGenus=&gMt=begin&sSpecies=&sMt=begin&multiPurpose=slsid&sMulti=&mMt=contain&searchSpec=s'.format(i+1)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
    elements = soup.find_all('div', style="border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 10px 0;")
    for element in elements:
        sp_name = element.i.text.strip()
        print(sp_name)
        status = element.find('span', class_ = ['success label', 'error label']).text.strip()
        print(status)
        author_family = element.i.next_sibling.strip().split('|')
        species_author = author_family[0].strip()
        family = author_family[1].strip()
        print(species_author)
        print(family)
        print()
        csv_writer.writerow([sp_name, species_author, status, family])

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: it may be obvious but I fail to understand. How does it know that range argument is pertaining to pages? sorry, I am absolutely new to programming.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that out but my question is how does it know that it should loop through pages?

Comment: `for i in range(151)` function generates numbers from 0 to 151 and then generated number passed to the url.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure of how your descriptions map to on the page but the following shows the principle of the loop and how to extract info.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
n = 4
results = []
headers = ['Success/Failure', 'Names', 'AuthorInfo', 'Family']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1,n + 1):
        r = s.get('https://wsc.nmbe.ch/search?sFamily=Salticidae&fMt=begin&sGenus=&gMt=begin&sSpecies=&sMt=begin&multiPurpose=slsid&sMulti=&mMt=contain&searchSpec=s&page={}'.format(page))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        failSucceed = [item.text for item in soup.select('.success, .error')]
        names = [item.text for item in soup.select('.ym-gbox div > i')]
        authorInfo = [item.next_sibling for item in soup.select('.ym-gbox div > i')]
        family= [item.split('|')[1] for item in authorInfo]   
        dfCurrent = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(failSucceed, names, authorInfo, family)))
        df = pd.concat([df, dfCurrent])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.csv", encoding='utf-8') 
print(df)
```

---

You can get the number of results pages with the following:

```
numPages = int(soup.select('[href*=search\?page]')[-2].text)
```