# To get the columns of the table also the first column containing link by clicking that link to get the data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have the below link

http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName=Pune

In this i want to scrape data in proper format in excel.The SurveyNo link contains the data when it is click i want the row-wise data with the data on clicking the survey number.

Also want the format that i have attached in the image (desired output in excel)

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
url = 'http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx? 
hDistName=Pune'
chrome_path =r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlTaluka')).select_by_value('5')
Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder5$ddlVillage')).select_by_value('1872')
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
table = soup.find("table" , attrs = {'id':'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate' })
with open('Baner.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-16',newline='') as csvfile:
     f = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
     f.writerow(['SurveyNo','Subdivision', 'Open ground', 'Resident house','Offices','Shops','Industrial','Unit (Rs./)'])  # headers
     rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:] 
     data=[]
     for tr in rows:  
         cols = tr.find_all('td')
         for td in cols:
              links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('SurveyNo')
              l =len(links)
              data12 =[]
              for i in range(l):
                   newlinks = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('SurveyNo')
                   newlinks[i].click()
                   soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
                   td1 = soup.find("textarea", attrs={'class': 'textbox'})
                   data12.append(td1.text)
                   data.append(td.text)
                   data.append(data12)
              print(data)
```

Please find the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSm9b.png). In that format I required the output of scrape data.

Comment: Your url isn't enough; it does get you to Pune, but it's asking also for a Taluka and Village.

Comment: I'm not getting anything like your image. Can you provide the Devanagari form of Baner? Maybe that will help.

Comment: image contains the required output on excel .  From the website i need to scrape the data and export it in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following and simply re-arrange columns at end along with desired renaming. There is the assumption `SurveyNo` exists for all wanted rows. I extract the hrefs from the SurveyNo cells which are actually executable strings you can pass to execute_script to show the survey numbers without worrying about stale element etc....

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName=Pune'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="5"]').click()
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="1872"]').click()
tableElement = d.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate')
table = pd.read_html(tableElement.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
table.columns = table.iloc[0]
table = table.iloc[1:]
table = table[table.Select == 'SurveyNo'] #assumption SurveyNo exists for all wanted rows
surveyNo_scripts = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in d.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_grdUrbanSubZoneWiseRate [href*='Select$']")]
i = 0
for script in surveyNo_scripts:
    d.execute_script(script)
    surveys = d.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea').text
    table.iloc[i]['Select'] = surveys
    i+=1   
print(table)
#rename and re-order columns as required
table.to_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

Output before rename and re-order:

[image]

---

In a loop you can concat all dfs and then write out in one go (my preference - shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54861771/6241235)) or later append as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135044/6241235)

Comment: Please explain not working as it worked when I ran it. You have noticed that I am not using your path to selenium for example? chrome_path =r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)   I also didn't need waits but those can be easily added.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Select'
showing above error

Comment: I am guessing it is appearing differently for you. If you do the code up to and including the line: table = table.iloc[1:]   and then print table. What is the name of the column that has the value 'SurveyNo' in it?

Comment: See my comment above

Comment: Actually the (table) output is in dataframe when I am going to add the next page data it is getting overwrite on the CSV file

Comment: When using the same code for url = http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName=Buldhana    the SurveyNo textarea data have not been added in the Select column.

Comment: For the url = http://www.igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName=Buldhana    I am selecting the option value = 1 for Talukas and option value = 1458 for village.

Comment: Yes i debug the program .From the code the surveys are printed properly but the issue is surveys are not able to fed  table.iloc[i]['Select']   . I thing the issue is for this one --- table.iloc[i]['Select'] = surveys

Comment: I will have a look this evening

Comment: Yet not found any solution. Please assist

Comment: What am I selecting for taluka and village?

Comment: option value = 1 for Talukas and option value = 1458 for village

Comment: Used the url = igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName=Buldhana

Comment: for the above url you will get the taluka option value = 1 and village option value = 1458

Comment: I’m in hospital and then at work. I will see what I can do over the weekend

Comment: Above code is working only for Pune District it is not working for other district talukas and villages